# Velocity field for uniform rotation

Tags: vector-fields

Let be $${\bf F}=-y\hat{\bf i}+x\hat{\bf j}$$

In [this](https://youtu.be/xrypSZU8cBE?t=757) video how did the professor figure out above field has angular velocity of $1$?

I understand $(-y,x)$ rotates the entire plane counter clockwise by $90$ degrees. So this vector field seems to rotate in counter clock wise direction at *uniform speed*. But how to work the actual angular velocity?

Answer (score 1):

The vector field corresponds to the system of differential equations
$$
dx/dt = -y
,\qquad
dy/dt = x
,
$$
which has the general solution
$$
x(t) = A \cos(t-\varphi_0),
\qquad
y(t) = A \sin(t-\varphi_0)
.
$$
From these formulas it follows that every solution curve (except the equilibrium point at the origin itself) is a circle centered at the origin, and that the period to go around such a circle is $2\pi$ (regardless of the radius).

You can also see this by expressing the differential equations in polar coordinates $x=r \cos \varphi$, $y=r \sin \varphi$,
which after some computation gives
$$
dr/dt = 0
,\qquad
d\varphi/dt = 1
.
$$